# Call setState in parent widget from other class

Tags: flutter

Please consider the following onTap function of a listTile inside a listViewBuilder:

```js
onTap: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Chat(id: uid, peerId: peerId, avatar: "",
      peerAvatar: avatar, peerName: name))).then((_) {
    setState(() {
      getChatUsers();
    });
  });
},
```

Basically it's pushing a new screen and when that screen pops it refreshes the listviewbuilder. This works fine when the listTile is under the same StateFullWidget as getChatUsers(), but I need to build the listTile in another Widget since it needs to be accessed also by another ListviewBuilder in another class (showSearch delegate > buildSuggestions). But doing so, does not give me access any more to:

```js
setState(() {
  getChatUsers();
});
```

Need some help figuring out a solution to this.

Comment: So basically you want to rebuild `ParentStatefulWidget` from `ChildStatefulWidget`. Is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a simple solution, but I finally ended up with a scopedmodel approach. Wrapped the app in a scopedmodel UserModel, then in the UserModel class:

```js
QuerySnapshot chatUsers;
Future getChatUsers() async {

  final QuerySnapshot chatters = await Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('NewMessages').where('chatters', arrayContains: firebaseUser.uid)
    .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
    .getDocuments();

  chatUsers = chatters;
  notifyListeners();
  
  return chatters;

}
```

So now I could use this when the pushed screen gets popped:

```js
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contexto) => Chat(id: uid, peerId: peerId, avatar: "",
    peerAvatar: avatar, peerName: name))).then((_) async {
  conversaUsers = await UserModel.of(contexto).getChatUsers();
});
```

And everywhere there's a ListviewBuilder waiting for new data (like in the parent Build and in searchdelegate buildsuggestions, I can now do:

```js
final QuerySnapshot chatUsers = ScopedModel.of < UserModel > (context, rebuildOnChange: true)
  .chatUsers;
```

I know that some may wonder why I didn't simply go for streambuilder or so, for updating the Listview Builders, but it's because I first needed to manipulate the dataset returned from firestore, before sending it down to the ListView builders.

Answer (score 1):

When you have extracted `ListTile` into another widget(which is the right way to do) you will have to add a property in Child say `final VoidCallback onTap;` and change the implementation of the child to as follows:

```
onTap: onTap,
```

And all the logic whether to navigate or to do something in an async callback should be handled by the parent as the child will be a dumb Stateless Widget. It should not be in control as to what should happen when a click is triggered. This reduces the reusability of the child widget.

Comment: I ended up using a scopedmodel, as shown in the answer, but if you'd like to elaborate with an example, I might be learning a new thing or two.

Answer (score -1):

One More way to do this is passing Parent Widget State to ChildWidget and using that Parent Widget you can call that function. Here is the example for the same.

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentWidgetState createState() => ParentWidgetState();
}

class ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  String title = 'Parent';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(title)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChildWidget(this)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeMsg() {
    setState(() {
      title = 'Parent 2';
    });
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ChildWidget({this.parentWidgetState});
  final ParentWidgetState parentWidgetState;

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text('Child')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
        onPressed: () {
          widget.parentWidgetState.changeMsg();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to put this sample code together. But here you're pushing the new screen from within the parent statefull widget, whereas my requirement was to push it in an independent widget which could be called by both parent widgets (listview builder in this case) and other classes connected to the parent (searchdelegate buildsuggestions in this case. I tried yor approach anyway but it threw a NoSuchMethod error when calling widget.parentWidgetState.changeMsg(); I finally ended up solving my issue with a scopedmodel, as shown in the answer.